# How to print only words that doesn't match between two files?

Tags: linux

FILE1:

```
cat
dog
house
tree
```

FILE2:

```
dog
cat
tree
```

I need to be printed only:
`house`

Comment: `diff FILE1 FILE2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$0]=1; next} !($0 in arr)' FILE2 FILE1
```

First build an associative array with words from FILE2 and than loop over FILE1 and only print those.

Using `comm`

```
comm -2 -3 <(sort FILE1) <(sort FILE2)
```

-2 suppresses lines unique to FILE2 and -3 suppresses lines found in both.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file1
cat
dog
house
tree

$ cat file2
dog
cat
tree

$ grep -vF -f file2 file1
house
```

The `-v` flag only shows non-matches, `-f` is for a filename to use as a filter, and `-F` is for exact matches (doesn't slow it down with any pattern matching).

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the words, you can sort the files, diff them, then use `sed` to filter out diff's symbols:

```
diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | sed -n '/^</s/^< //p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk is an option here:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { arr[$1]="1" } NR != FNR { if (arr[$1] == "") { print $0 } } ' file2 file1
```

Create an array called arr, using the contents of file2 as indexes. Then with file1, look at each entry and check to see if an entry in the array arr exists. If it doesn't, print.